# Leaf Node 'when' or 'must' statement Usage

Tags: ietf-netmod-yang

I am in the process of learning OpenDayLight and Yang and can't figure out how to put a constraint on a leaf node. I have a leaf node (vpn-id). When the l3vpn-type node equals 'bgp', I want data for this one to be allowed for vpn-id. If the leaf node does not equal 'bgp' and the vpn-id is entered I want to throw an error.  I have tested this in OpenDayLight and it always allows me to save the data no matter what the data has in it.

Also, I am having a hard time finding Yang examples so I can teach myself. Suggestions are welcome.

```
module DaveTest {
 namespace "urn:aaa:ddd:DaveTest";
 prefix dave-module;

 description "Dave testing file";

 revision "2017-04-17" {
      description "Initial version.";
 }

 container testing-vars {

      list test-list {

           key "vpn-transaction-id l3vpn-type";
           unique "vpn-transaction-id";

           leaf vpn-transaction-id {
                type string;
           }

           leaf l3vpn-type {
                type enumeration {
                     enum "bgp";
                     enum "static";
                     enum "gre tunnel";
                }
                mandatory true;
           }

           leaf vpn-id {
                when "../l3vpn-type = 'bgp'";
                type string;
           }
      }              
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of the `when` statement is correct. You have made `vpn-id` conditional, so that it is only allowed to appear if `l3vpn-type` has a value of `bgp`. Perhaps it is not working as expected due to a bug in ODL.

If you wish to learn about YANG, reading [ietf-netmod-yang](/questions/tagged/ietf-netmod-yang) tag wiki would be a good start (there are links at the bottom). There are repositories of YANG modules made by various groups that can be found online, such as [this one](https://github.com/OpenROADM/OpenROADM_MSA_Public). Perhaps reading standard modules would be a better start, as they are peer reviewed and follow guidelines for YANG authors. They can be found in inside [published RFCs](https://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/netmod/documents/), usually with their name containing "YANG data model for" phrase.

Answer (score 0):

You can add must statement as the following:

```
leaf vpn-id {
    must "../l3vpn-type = 'bgp'";
    type string;
}
```